# What is the use of var app = express(); in the process of creating a Node.Js Application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to the world of Node.js.I am trying to learn through an example.I have encountered the following statements in the "app.js" .

```
  var express = require("express");----->1
  var app = express(); --------->2
```

So I understand the first statement is to load express module .What is the need for second statement??

Inorder to load a MYSQL module in my app.js we use

```
 var mysql = require("MYSQL");
```

We access SQL properties by mysql.connect("") etc.

so why cannot we write  "express.get()" instead of "app.get()"????

Why do we need var express = require("express");??

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Because that is a design decision of the corresponding library. In mysql you have multiple main factory functions `createPool`, `createPoolCluster` and `createConnection`, for `express` only one, this is most likely the reason for this difference. But in the end its up to the library creator how to design the api.

Comment: @t.niese Hey,Thanks for the quick reply.However,I am having a little bit of difficulty in understanding your statement.Can you please illustrate through an example? If possible? :) :)

Comment: `app.get(...)` is equal to `connection.query(...)` and `express()` is equal to `mysql.createConnection(...)`. `mysql` is in this case just a _namespace_ grouping the factory functions of the mysql library, express returns the main factory function directly. They also could have decided that you need to do `var app = express.createApp()` but they didn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`express` is a module that can be used to create more than one application.

```
var ex = require('express')
```

puts this module into the variable `ex`. Once you have a reference to the module, you can use it to create application. Each module has its own API. According to the expressjs documentation - http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html, the module is in fact a function that can be used to create applications

```
var app1 = ex();
var app2 = ex();
```

you could for example want to have several web applications listening on different ports.

If you only want one application (but it would be less readable) you could write

```
var app = require('express')();
```

Answer (score 6):

The real difference between `require('express')` and `express()` is that `require('express')` allows you to have access to any public functions or properties exposed by [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports).

The `express()` syntax is the equivalent of saying `new express()`. It creates a new instance of `express` that you can then assign to a variable and interact with.

That is why the standard creation pattern for Express is

```
// Import the Express module
var express = require('express');

// Create a new Express Instance
var app = express();
```